# How to Listen for trackpad events in MacOS SwiftUI app

Tags: macos, cocoa, swiftui, appkit

I have a SwiftUI view that a user can drag to dismiss. On MacOS, this will translate the view if the user clicks and drags with their mouse. I'd like to allow them to swipe via the trackpad (similar to how the apple mail app can swipe messages). How do I do this with SwiftUI? What events do I listen for?

```
        .offset(self.offset)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    self.offset = gesture.translation
            }
        )
```

Comment: You mean slide to delete?

Comment: yeah slide to delete or mark as read etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up supporting this by overriding `NSWindow.scrollWheel(with event:)` that includes a call to `event.trackSwipeEvent`

Answer (score 0):

Slide to delete is only available at `List` in macOS. At the moment you can not display custom ones.

To get the slide to delete in your list, you have to add the `.onDelete` property to the List...

```
.onDelete(perform: action)
```

.. which will enable slide to delete.

Comment: is there a way to listen to trackpad events in SwiftUI so I can build this view myself?